# Запустить python скрипт на сервере

Tags: python, сервер, ubuntu

Помню была какая-то команда

```
python script.py & [что-то там]
```

которая запускала скрипт и можно было закрывать терминал, уходить с сервера, а скрипт продолжал работать. Может кто напомнить?

Comment: Может быть что-то типа:

    nohup python script.py > /var/log/myscript.log 2>&1 &

nohup ... - отвязывает ввод/вывод
... > ... - перенаправляет вывод в файл
... 2>&1 - поток ошибок перенаправляет в поток вывода
... & - запуск в фоне

Comment: @BOPOH, да, это оно. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто

```
python script.py &
```

запустит скрипт в фоновом режиме. Чтобы "вернуть" его, нужна команда

```
fg %1
```

Но для сервера лучше использовать [screen](http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/articles/soft/screen2.phtml), чтобы была возможность подключиться к процессу при необходимости.

P.S.
Если скрипт уже работает, то можно остановить его (не завершить, а "поставить на паузу" командой ctrl+z) и продолжить выполнение в фоне командой

```
bg %1
```